# Parallel processing on GPU (MXNet) and CPU using Python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, parallel-processing, gpu, mxnet

Hi have a data processing pipeline and I want to optimise it by running some processing threads on the CPUs while running MXNet prediction model on the GPU at the same time (Python 3.6).

The idea that I would like to apply is the following (suppose that I have N GPUs on my machine):

- A GPU Job Dispatcher reads a sequence of N frames from a video, and send each frame to one GPU.
- Each GPU process its frame and predict its content with MXNet.
- Once all N GPUs has finished their predictions, I want **at the same time** to:

  1. Send the prediction output to a queue.
  2. read and process the next N frames in the GPU.
- The queue is consumed by a multithreaded process that runs on CPU.

Here is a visual description to the workflow:

[image]

The idea is to take advantage of the idle CPUs while the GPUs are busy processing the frames.

By using the threading library, I was successful in reading and processing the first N frames, but the GPUs are not able to process the next batch of frames.

**Please note, the source code below is simplified to clarify the workflow.**

Here is the code of the function that reads the frames and dispatches them to the gpus and then sends the outputs to the cpu queue:

```
def dispatch_jobs(video_capture, detection_workers, number_of_gpu, cpu_queue):
    # detection_workers is a list of N similar MXNet models, each one works on a different GPU
    is_last_frame = False
    while not is_last_frame:
        frames_batch = []
        for i in range(0, number_of_gpu):
            success, frame = read_frame_from_video(video_capture)
            if not success:
                logging.warning("Can't receive frame. Exiting.")
                is_last_frame = True
                break
            frames_batch.append(frame)

        workers = []
        for detection_worker_id in range(0, len(frames_batch)):
            frame_image = frames_batch[detection_worker_id]
            thread = Thread(target=detection_workers[detection_worker_id].predict, kwargs={'image': frame_image})
            workers.append(thread)

        for w in workers: w.start()
        for w in workers: w.join()

        # sending to the CPU queue
        for detection_worker_id in range(0, len(frames_batch)):
            detector_output = detection_workers[detection_worker_id].output
            cpu_queue.put(detector_output)

    logging.info("While loop is broken... putting -1 in the queue")
    cpu_queue.put(-1)

    return
```

As explained above, there is a consumer thread that reads the outputs from the `cpu_queue`, and send them to a multi-threaded function (on CPU), here is the code of the consumption function:

```
def consume_cpu_queue(cpu_queue):
    while cpu_queue.empty():
        logging.info("Sleeping 1 second")
        time.sleep(1)

    prediction_output = cpu_queue.get()
    if prediction_output == -1:
        return

    process_output_multithread(prediction_output)
    consume_cpu_queue()

def process_output_multithread(pred_output, number_of_process):
    workers = []
    for i in range(0, number_of_process):
        thread = Thread(target=process, kwargs={'pred_output': pred_output})
        workers.append(thread)

    for w in workers: w.start()
    for w in workers: w.join()
    return

# Here is how the consumer thread is initiated
cpu_consumer_thread = Thread(target=consume_cpu_queue)

# Here is how I run the application
cpu_consumer_thread.start()
dispatch_jobs(video_capture, detection_workers)
cpu_consumer_thread.join()
```

I have have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58604741/cpu-gpu-parallel-programming-python), but I am not sure if Numba can solve my issue.

Any suggestion or pointer would be greatly helpful.

Comment: this may help: https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/machine-learning/parallelizing-across-multiple-cpu-gpus-to-speed-up-deep-learning-inference-at-the-edge/

Comment: did you try/look at async/await ?

Comment: @RyabchenkoAlexander I have no real experience here, any example is appreciated

Comment: look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently